# Kendo DropDownList not displaying selected item

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, html-select

I am trying to use a pair of Kendo dropdown lists to filter a dataset in AngularJS. One uses a static ObservableArray datasource to filter the dataset by status; the other datasource is a set of distinct values from the "regionID" column of the dataset, also stored as an ObservableArray. When the status dropdown changes, the region dropdown is supposed to reload the list of regions from the newly-filtered data. This works, but the selected value ends up blanked out, even though the model that's supposed to represent the selected value still has the correct value, and the data is still correctly filtered by that same value. Opening the dropdown and then clicking off of it causes it to then display that value as it should.

Here is what the HTML looks like:

```
<select name="filterByRegion" style="width: 180px;" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedRegion" ng-change="onRegionFilterChange(selectedRegion)" kendo-drop-down-list k-options="regionFilterOptions"></select>
<select name="accountStatus" style="width: 180px;" class="form-control" ng-model="status" ng-change="onAccountStatusChange(status)" kendo-drop-down-list k-options="accountStatusOptions"></select>
```

Here are the two "onChange" methods from the controller:

```
        $scope.onAccountStatusChange = function(status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            updateRegionFilterList();
        };
        $scope.onRegionFilterChange = function(selectedRegion) {
            $scope.selectedRegion = selectedRegion;
        };
```

And lastly, here is the updateRegionFilterList method:

```
        var updateRegionFilterList = function () {

            $scope.regions.empty();

            angular.forEach($scope.accounts, function(account) {
                if (account.reviewStatus === $scope.status) {
                    if ($scope.regions.indexOf(account.regionID) <= -1) {
                        $scope.regions.push(account.regionID);
                    }
                }
            });

            $scope.regions.sort();
            $scope.regions.unshift("Filter By Region:");

            if ($scope.regions.indexOf(tempRegion) <= -1) {
                $scope.selectedRegion = "Filter By Region";
            }
        };
```

I have tried many ways of working around this, including trying to preserve and reload the selectedRegion value, splicing out unneeded regions instead of emptying the ObservableArray, etc., and I have checked everything in the debugger and all of the values are correct (no obvious race conditions either).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had mixed kendo and angular configurations with the dropdowns and was relying on an angular process to update the data, which wasn't updating the Kendo MVVM stuff properly. Switching it to pure Kendo did the trick.